# How to change n last digit in ln binary on linux shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script

I want to change n last digit: 
ex:

```
A=3
y=00001010
y1="$(echo $y| tail -c $A)"
```

I want to change the last 3 digits to 000 and 111

what command I need to use and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can use:

```
#!/bin/bash
y=00001010
A=3
y=${y:0:-$A}
y_zero=$y
y_one=$y
for((i=0;i<$A;i++))
do
y_zero=$y_zero"0"
y_one=$y_one"1"
done
echo $y_zero $y_one
```

Output will be

```
00001000 00001111
```

Comment: hmmm how to use binary-octet format in shell, like y=00000001 count as 1 right, so when A>1 i have  substring expression < 0

Comment: i cut the ip add ect: 10.0.0.0/4 into octet
then when i change the octet to binary, it only appear like 1010 not 00001010, how can i do that

Comment: You should ask a separate question.